Can I exclude maven resource folder from a Java module?
I created two Maven projects 'javafx' and 'commonfx' to reproduce an error.

module commonfx {
   exports commonfx.calculator;
}


module javafx {
       requires javafx.controls;
       requires javafx.graphics;
       requires javafx.fxml;
       requires commonfx;
       opens org.example to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;
}

Both projects have an resource folder. They do not export those folders but anyway I am getting constantly error messages:
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer

java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: 
Package bundle in both module javafx and module commonfx

Whenever I rerun the application, I am getting a new error message. But each time a resource folder is same named in both modules.
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer

java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: 
Package images in both module commonfx and module javafx

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer

java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: 
Package main.resources.images in both module commonfx and module javafx.

Used technologies:

Java 21
JavaFX SDK 21
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers Version: 2024-03
Maven 3.9.6

Is it possible that the maven resource folder are getting ignored?
Code to reproduce the exception:
Project commonfx
package commonfx.calculator;

public class FxCalculator {

    public FxCalculator() {
        super();
    }

    public Integer calculate() {
        return 2;
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>common.fx</groupId>
   <artifactId>commonfx</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <properties>
      <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <javafx.version>21</javafx.version>
      <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
         <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
         <version>21.0.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
         <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
         <version>${javafx.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
         <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
         <version>${javafx.version}</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>

Project javafx
package org.example;

import commonfx.calculator.FxCalculator;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Javafx extends Application {
    private FxCalculator calculator;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
        String javafxVersion = System.getProperty("javafx.version");
        calculator = new FxCalculator();
        Label l = new Label("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + ", running on Java " + javaVersion + "." + " Number FX: " + calculator.calculate());
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(l), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>org.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <properties>
      <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <javafx.version>21</javafx.version>
      <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
         <version>3.2.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>net.rgielen</groupId>
         <artifactId>javafx-weaver-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
         <version>1.3.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
         <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
         <version>21.0.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
         <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
         <version>${javafx.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
         <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
         <version>${javafx.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>common.fx</groupId>
         <artifactId>commonfx</artifactId>
         <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
               <mainClass>org.example.Javafx</mainClass>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>


Curious to learn, if bundle is really a package?

Yeah. It is not even a package and it is not getting exported. Any idea how to solve it? Maybe to remove from buildpath?

Your package in commonfx is commonfx.calculator.  Why not put the resources for that in src/main/resources/commonfx/calculator?  Then they are properly encapsulated in the module.  According to the module spec: "A module is a named, self-describing collection of code and data. Its code is organized as a set of packages containing types, i.e., Java classes and interfaces; its data includes resources and other kinds of static information.".

If you want to further break it down by resource type as you do currently, then src/main/resources/commonfx/calculator/bundle and src/main/resources/commonfx/calculator/images, with exports commonfx.calculator.bundle; and exports commonfx.calculator.images; in your module definition.  I didn't try it, but should work.

Folders that are exported from your source hierarchy to your build become packages in the build, whether they contain class files or resources. Resources are bundled into packages and accessed via the packages containing them, just like classes are. Packages that are exported should be uniquely named (the convention is to use reverse domain names where possible). At a minimum you should make the packages uniquely named (again, whether they contain classes or resources).

By the way, not only the package names, but also the module names should be unique, e.g. org.example.my_product.app instead of javafx.

@jewelsea I added some code to reproduce. Your approach 'first renaming resource packages in a unique way and secondly exporting them' is not working. Is it working fo you?

Yes, my suggested approach works for me.  I added an answer demonstrating the approach.

TL;DR: This is a split package problem. The solution is to either:

Rename your packages so that they are unique.

Rename your packages to something that is not a valid package name (only an option if the packages do not contain class files).

Make your code non-modular and place your code and its dependencies (except JavaFX) on the class-path.


See jewelsea's answer for a working example of the first solution, as well as reasons why the third solution is likely the best for your (the questioner's) specific scenario.

The Problem
The error you are seeing is due to two modules containing the same package. This is not something that should be solved by excluding resource folders via Maven.
Resource-only Packages
First, it is not a requirement for a package to contain class files to be considered a package. Really the only important thing is that the package has a valid name and contains something, whether that be a class file or some other resource. Plus, class files are basically just a special type of resource. From the perspective of a (typical) class loader, resources and class files are found and opened in the exact same way.
In other words, bundle, config, and images are all packages in your case. Those are valid package names and they contain resources. Also, since those are packages contained in the module, the resources within them are encapsulated (a feature based on packages).
Split Packages
When two (or more) modules contain a package with the same name, that package is said to be "split". The Java Platform Module System ensures that when a split package exists, the two (or more) modules do not interfere with each other. It ensures this at two different steps in the process of loading modules.
During module resolution, the resolution can fail if:

Two or more modules in the configuration export the same package to a module that reads both. This includes the case where a module M containing package p reads another module that exports p to M.

Then a module layer is defined, which can fail if:

Two or more modules with the same package are mapped to the same class loader.

Neither bundle nor images is exported, so your two modules are being resolved just fine. The error you see occurs when the layer is being defined, hence LayerInstantiationException as the exception type. Your two modules are being mapped to the same class loader (the system/application class loader).
Basically, split packages are completely forbidden for modules loaded via the --module-path command line option. Both the module readability graph and whether or not a split package is exported are irrelevant.
Also see Java 9 overlapping non-exported packages.

Solutions
There are at least three solutions: use unique package names, use invalid package names, or make your code non-modular.
Unique Package Names
You should use unique package names, even when the package is not going to be exported. A conventional way to come up with a unique package name is by combining a reversed domain name with a name that identifies the artifact. These two things are typically pulled from the Maven coordinates of said artifact. For example, if you have:
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>commonsfx</artifactId>

In your POM, then your package name would be com.example.commonsfx. That would also be a good name for your module.
See jewelsea's answer for a full example.
Use Invalid Package Names
If you rename bundle and images to something that is not a valid package name, then they will no longer be considered packages. This will let you have the same "package" in multiple modules, but it will also mean the resources within those "packages" are no longer encapsulated.
Warning: This is only an option if the packages do not contain class files.
Make Your Code Non-Modular
If you make your code non-modular and place it on the class-path then your split packages will no longer be a problem. For your specific case, this is likely the best solution. See the end of jewelsea's answer for reasons why.

An example modular app that depends on another module containing resources for images and text.
The app consists of:

A org.example.calculator module that includes the core functions and resources for the calculator implementation.
A org.example.calculatorapp module which is a JavaFX application that depends on the calculator module for its functions and resources.

Principles used are those related in Slaw's answer, and other comments on the question. Resources are encapsulated in the same packages that are defined in each module and the packages defined in each module have separate names.

Calculator module
This is the module which is depended on.
The resources needed are all encapsulated in the module by placing them in the same package location of the rest of the module code, which is then exported from the module in the module-info.
pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>calculator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>calculator</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

src/main/java/module-info.java
module org.example.calculator {
    exports org.example.calculator;
}

src/main/java/org/example/calculator/Calculator.java
package org.example.calculator;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Calculator {
    private final ResourceBundle resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
            "org.example.calculator.calculator-resources"
    );

    public String add(int a, int b) {
        return a + resources.getString("add") + b + resources.getString("equals") + (a+b);
    }

    public String subtract(int a, int b) {
        return a + resources.getString("subtract") + b + resources.getString("equals") + (a-b);
    }

    public String getIconUrlString() {
        return Objects.requireNonNull(
                Calculator.class.getResource(
                        "calc.png"
                )
        ).toExternalForm();
    }
}

src/main/resources/org/example/calculator/calculator-resources.properties
add=+
subtract=-
equals==

src/main/resources/org/example/calculator/calc.png

Calculator App module
pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>calculatorApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>calculatorApp</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>21.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>calculator</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

src/main/java/module-info.java
module org.example.calculatorapp {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires org.example.calculator;

    exports org.example.calculatorapp;
}

src/main/java/org/example/calculatorapp/CalculatorApp.java
package org.example.calculatorapp;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.example.calculator.Calculator;

public class CalculatorApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();

        Image calculatorImage = new Image(
                calculator.getIconUrlString(),
                64, 64, true, true, false
        );
        Label title = new Label("Calculator");
        title.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 32px;");
        title.setGraphic(new ImageView(calculatorImage));

        GridPane grid = new GridPane(10, 10);
        grid.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 20px;");

        Label aLabel = new Label("a:");
        TextField aField = new TextField("10");
        grid.addRow(0, aLabel, aField);

        Label bLabel = new Label("b:");
        TextField bField = new TextField("2");
        grid.addRow(1, bLabel, bField);

        Button add = new Button("add");
        Button subtract = new Button("subtract");
        grid.addRow(2, add, subtract);

        Label equationLabel = new Label("Equation:");
        Label equationResult = new Label();
        grid.addRow(3, equationLabel, equationResult);

        add.setOnAction(e ->
                equationResult.setText(
                        calculator.add(
                                Integer.parseInt(aField.getText()),
                                Integer.parseInt(bField.getText())
                        )
                )
        );

        subtract.setOnAction(e ->
                equationResult.setText(
                        calculator.subtract(
                                Integer.parseInt(aField.getText()),
                                Integer.parseInt(bField.getText())
                        )
                )
        );

        VBox layout = new VBox(10, title, grid);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(12));

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}

Notes
Recommendation: for code containing automatic modules
The above example is for a fully modularized system where the code has well-defined module-info.java files.
Your javafx project module in your question does not match the dependencies you have in your pom.xml.
The Maven project includes Spring dependencies, but the module definition does not require Spring modules. As of Spring 6, Spring uses automatic modules. Many benefits of modularized code are lost when automatic modules are used.
So, rather than using the approach in this answer, make the project non-modular, delete the module-info, and put javafx modules on the module path using VM parameters.

Using the third approach I still need to figure out how to add automatically the library 'javax.smartcardio'. The module smartcardio is optional, but it is still included in the SE. So if I want to use it, I have to require it in a module-info.java. Otherwise I need to add it manually  to the Project after each Maven Update. Any ideas how to solve this issue?

What is the "third approach"?  javax.smartcardio -> That software isn't mentioned in your question.  Perhaps ask a new question with an [mcve] specifically for that. "I have to require it in a module-info.java" -> That is probably a misconception.  There is very little Java software written that absolutely requires it works as a module.  "I need to add it manually to the Project after each Maven Update" -> that also seems like a misconception.

@Biilie For when your application is non-modular: If javax.smartcardio is not being resolved, then you can add it via --add-modules. If that does not help, or you need further help, then I second the recommendation to ask a new question with a [mre].

@jewelsea I created a new post: link
